# The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, listview, youtube-data-api

From Listview row Click I am opening YoutubePlayerVeiwActivity and it shows error of

YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.ListView{7540501 VFED..C.. .F....ID 0,0-1280,494 #7f100135 app:id/listView_profile}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 30, top: 504, right: 30, bottom: -390 (these should all be positive).

code is inside listView is:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, YouTubePlayerActivity.class); 
                        intent.putExtra(YouTubePlayerActivity.EXTRA_VIDEO_ID, Utility.extractYTId(feedListData.getUrl()));                                                    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: any solution for this

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy No not yet, But you can use iframe inside webview, or same as YouTube app you can show list of videos and on click you can play video in new screen.

Comment: Actually in my case i need to implement in recycle-view it's working fine in first time,  when i scroll up and down video view covered black screen but video playing i'm here audio..